# Flexible Potentiometer Strip

Tags: resistors, resistance, potentiometer, materials

Recently I've been working on a project and have encountered a problem. The gadget I'm working on has a kind of knob that rotates and acts as a potentiometer.

The problem is I can't use a normal potentiometer because of design difficulties (I can't put anything under the knob).

What I've been thinking about is if I could make a sort of potentiometer strip that I could flex around the knob and then attach a tap to the knob. Of course I can wind a NiChrome wire and make such a strip myself, but if I'm going to increase the scale of production I'd rather use something already existing for that.

What could I use for this application?

I thought about force sensitive resistors that work kinda like a potentiometer, but they are quite expensive. The resistance value I'm talking about is around 100 kΩ. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If possible you can state your design challenges in numericals. How much space do you have. If one can suggest other existing products, it will come as aid.

Comment: "you can't put anything under the knob": well, how does the knob stay in place then? Can you make a drawing?

Answer (score 2):

This used to be so easy ... you're looking for an edgewise potentiometer, which was built into the knob. Often only the edge of the knob projected through the case. But try as I can, I can't find them nowadays.

You might try building [this](http://uk.farnell.com/bourns/3382g-1-103g/position-sensor-resistive-3pin/dp/1717387) into a knob that fits over it, with a short D-shaft projecting through the cavity to turn it.

[image]

Comment: I like the surface mount idea. Perhaps even something like this with a big knob to cover the whole thing.  -  http://uk.farnell.com/bourns/ptv09a-4020f-b103/pot-rotary-10kohm-9mm-20/dp/2469524

Comment: Hey that might actually solve the problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use a cheap and small 100k trimpot